# Как передать пост-запрос со страницы браузерного отображения данных в DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Хочу пользоваться ручным тестированием апишек, но не знаю как передавать пост-запросы со страницы браузерного отображения данных.

Сейчас всё упирается в csrf.
Нужно передавать самому csrf-token? Если да, то как?

Или может есть возможность отключать проверку на csrf?

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше.

Comment: csrf-token можно передать как параметр POST запроса. Вот пример как его можно получить: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: @Александр Курмазов, а как его передать в пост? Что нужно писать?

Comment: когда я работал с DRF, я делал POST-запрос через Ajax с [вот такой](https://imgur.com/9BGuwlI) предустановкой

Comment: @Александр Курмазов, спасибо, но вот не вижу как добавить заголовок в запрос со страницы браузерного отображения данный. Как они предполагали люди этим будут пользоваться мне что-то непонятно.

Comment: что подразумевается под "страница браузерного отображения данных"?

Comment: @Александр Курмазов, это страничка адрес которой заканчивается либо на .api, если опция подключена, либо на `/?format=api`, там на этой страничке ещё в меню GET, можно выбирать тип отбражения.

Comment: Если ты говоришь про [эту](https://imgur.com/a/zeWlQNy) страницу, то просто указываешь параметры необходимые и жмешь на кнопку POST, csrf токен тут даже и не требуется

Comment: @Александр Курмазов, именно про эту, но у меня вьюха возвращает ошибку: `"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set."`, то есть при гет-запросе на нужную мне страницу нужно прописать токен в куки?

Comment: @Александр Курмазов, спасибо, что помог разобраться, был отключен миддлвар для цсрф :-) А я грешил на разработчиков DRF.

Comment: Бывает) Не за что